# the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+(-1)^n +\ln(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+(-1)^n +\ln(n)}$ converge?

Comment: If the series starts from $0$ it will not be defined due to the logarithm.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hint:

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{1 + (-1)^n + \ln(n)} = \frac{1}{(-1)^n (\ln(n) +1)+1} = \frac{(-1)^n(\ln(n) +1)-1}{(\ln(n) +1)^2-1} \\ =  \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n) + 1 -1/(\ln(n)+1)}-  \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2 + \ln(n)}$$